# Docker setup for two apps

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to setup two apps within a dockerfile. Tried to follow the tutorial on dockers website but keep getting an error that `python manage.py runserver` does not exist.

**Purpose:**
I am trying to run two different programs (client & server) but setting them up with same dockerfile and then choose which one to run within docker-compose (if possible, otherwise two different dockerfiles).

**Structure:**
The files is build like following:

```
root
    client
          client.py
          *other fíles/dirs connected to client.py*
    server
          manage.py
          *other fíles/dirs connected to manage.py*
```

The client connects to the server which should be run in another container (in best case). And in order to start the server the following is run: `python manage.py runserver`.

The server shall always run at start but client should have a schedule or cronjob which will eventually be implemented to run once a day. Therefor I dont think they can run on same container.

**What I tried:**

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine3.12

RUN apk add -U --no-cache gcc build-base linux-headers ca-certificates python3-dev libffi-dev libressl-dev libxslt-dev

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV "/venv"
RUN python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

COPY requirements.txt /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /server

COPY /server/ /server/

RUN mkdir /client

COPY /client/ /client/

EXPOSE 5000

WORKDIR /server/
CMD ["python", "./manage.py runserver"]
```

I am not very familiar with dockerfile as I am with docker-compose and I dont seem to find a way to inspect the container I built to see how the structure of the folders.

Comment: That `CMD` line is trying to run a script named `manage.py runserver`, with a space in the filename, with no arguments.  You probably want to split it into two words.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to fix one of the problems. I noticed that I got a problem with volumes as well. Since the server consist of a database I would like to access it outside of the container. However when starting the container with: docker run --name temp_server -p 5000:5000 -v /docker_test:/web rp. It complains that the file manage.py doesnt exist